# Hudson - Testing plugins of a framework

Tags: php, unit-testing, hudson

I'm new to Hudson and I have the need to run Unit Tests of several PHP Plugins, written for different frameworks (e.g. Wordpress, Drupal and so on). To work, these plugins need to be installed into the framework and a boostrap file has to be loaded first.

I was wondering how should I proceed to configure Hudson to tell it to export the plugin from Source Control inside a subdirectory of the framework, and then run the tests. I was thinking that the framework could be installed once, together with its standard database, and never touched (I would run separate tests against different framework version). Eventually, database could be restored at every run, to make sure previous issues don't interfere with the test.

My question is: is it possible to do the above? Summarizing:
 - Install each framework on the system, in a folder dedicated to Hudson and with a standard database.
 - At each run, let Hudson restore the standard database (to prevent "contamination" from previous runs).
 - Let Hudson fetch plugins' files from SVN and store them in the appropriate folder, depending on the framework.
 - Run the tests.

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use a main job + ant configuration file for the cms itself and if it is rebuild other jobs can start from it and use the directories created by the main job.

i've done it that way for one cms and it works, but i've used jenkins instead of hudson, dunno how big the differences are now.

you may e.g. check for source control changes in the main job. you can tell other jobs to start whenever that main job is rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my case, the CMS would not be stored in any source control, as I would use a precise point in time version. I'd need to find a way to "provide it" to Hudson as "just copy it in your own working folder and export the plugin(s) from source control into a subfolder of the CMS".

Comment: apache ant is very powerful and should do it, but i'm not that familar with it to provide further help, sorry